# Firebase Authentication method verify if sign-In has been successful

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've tried to make a method that gives me a boolean when I've been successfully signed with Firebase Authentication, the problem is that I'm always getting false, even when the log says it's not true.

Here's my method:

```
public boolean signIn(String email, String password, final Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
        final boolean[] resultado = {false};

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [START sign_in_with_email]
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            userFire = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            resultado[0] = true;

                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:succes");



                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());

                        }

                    }
                });

        return resultado[0];
    }
```

Any idea how to make sure that I get the correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase APIs are *asynchronous*, meaning that `signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the Task it returns will be called some time later.  There are no guarantees about how long it will take.  Because that method returns immediately, the value you're returning (`resultado[0]`) will not have been populated from the callback yet.

Basically, you're trying to return a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous.  That's not a good idea.  You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

To learn more about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous and what you can expect from them, [read this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a `boolean` to check if sign in was correct or not.

It is done for you in the below method:

```
  mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
```

if the sign in authentication was successful then the user will be able to sign in.

You can add a `Log` to check or a toast that appears to a user, that will tell him if successful or not.

This is an alternative as the returning a boolean won't work.